# How to make a simple simple sh file to delete a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to make a simple script to delete some auto generated folders.

On windows, this is how I do it in a batch file:

```
@RD /S /Q "bin"
@RD /S /Q "bin-int"
@RD /S /Q "workspace"
```

On linux, this is how I'm trying to do it in a .sh file.

```
rm -r bin
rm -r bin-int
rm -r workspace
```

But none of the folders are getting deleted. But if I try to use touch, it is able to create a new file, and well as make directories.

This is my first day using linux, so ELI5 if possible, thanks!

This is how my folder structure looks:

[image]

Comment: That looks like it should work. Do you get any error messages? Where are the directories, and where are *you* when you run the script? How do you run the script?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have the .sh file in the directory where the folders are located. If I use the command line and manually type the commands, it works. But when using the .sh file, it fails. I even tried running the .sh file via command line, and it returns a file or directory not found error.

Comment: When you refer to a file with a relative path (including just the name, e.g. `bin-int`), it looks for it in the process's working directory. This has *nothing* to do with where the script is, it's inherited from whatever process started the script. How are you starting the script?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I just double click on the script and select "Run in Terminal". I assume that when I do that the process starts in the same folder as the script is. The script I am trying to run is CleanUp_Linux.sh. RunPremake_Linux.sh works fine.

Comment: It probably runs in your home folder, though it may depend on the OS. Try adding the command `pwd` (**p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory) to your script and see what it prints. You can probably use `cd "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/" || exit` at the beginning of the script to move to the script's directory (see [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I found the issue and posted the answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the issue.

When I created CleanUp_Linux.sh, I made a copy of CleanUp_Windows.bat and edited it from there. This means that CleanUp_Linux.sh is saved with an extra '/r' carriage return at the end of every line because that's how Windows saves text files.

To solve the issue, I simply created a new CleanUp_Linux.sh in Linux, and copy pasted the contents over. You can also use the dos2unix command.